# Gradle application plugin: Modify workingDir property

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

I simply want to modify the directory where the program is run. Normally, it's run from the project root, which annoys me a little bit, because testing the program out can be quite annoying, since my program generates files and folders where it is being run.

A [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task has a property called [`JavaExec#workingDir`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:workingDir), which would be this exact property I wanted to modify to something different of my choice.

My question is: How do I modify the `gradle run` task in order to access this property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access a property of a task by using `tasks.<TaskToModify>.property = YourValue`.

So, in this case, you would have to do this:

```
File runningDir = new File('build/run/')
runningDir.mkdirs()
tasks.run.workingDir = runningDir
```

The [`File#mkdirs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs--) call is neccessary, since if the directories do not exist, the call to your system-dependent java executable will cause a error.

Comment: With gradle 7.3.3 (not sure since which version), I have to use `tasks.run.get().workingDir = runningDir`

Comment: A few gradle versions later, and none of this works anymore.