# How to change the working directory using JavaFX with Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx

The title says all. How do I change the working/runtime directory when using JavaFX with Gradle in Eclipse?

Basically, I have a project that requires log4j and initiates a basic logger which uses the "logs/" directory from the place the jar is run. This directory is being made in the home of the source, but I want it to be made in the "run/" directory. I'm assuming for other files that will be created, they will also have this same issue.

My build.gradle is this:

```
// Plugins
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

// Repositories
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

// Dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.12.0'
}

// JavaFX
javafx {
    version = '12'
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}
mainClassName = 'net.protolauncher.backtest2.ProtoLauncher'
```

I am using Eclipse to run it, but this issue also occurs when just running the `run` task. I tried changing the `Working Directory` in the "Gradle Project" run configuration, but it didn't work at all (it just loaded forever).

To give an example, here's the directory of my source code: `DirectoryX`. Now, I made a folder in here called "run", like so: `DirectoryX/run`. When I run the program, I want my logs to go into `DirectoryX/run/logs` and similar files to go into the run directory. However, when running with Gradle my log files are being created in `DirectoryX/logs`.

This probably made no sense, but if it did, I really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching online to no avail, [I finally found a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30594197/6472449) that solves the question. Turns out, JavaExec is a complicated thing, and what I was doing was specific to that, NOT JavaFx.

Comment: So how do you solve the issue?