# Customize working directory run gradle run task / project structure for web application

Tags: gradle, webserver, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on small web app and I want to serve static files. I'm using `application` plugin. Part of it is `distribution` plugin which copies `src/main/dist` files into distribution zip. Running application with `gradlew run` uses project dir as working directory. For this reason static files are not found.

Is there a simple way to change working directory for `run` task?

Is there any other recommended structure for web app gradle project setup?

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar case when running './gradlew run' of a Kotlin (console) app. The default working directory is the application directory, but IntelliJ uses the root project directory by default.

I have managed to change the working directory by setting the `workingDir` property of the run task. The list of properties can be found on https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

```
application {
    mainClass.set("myproject.HelloKt")

    // Change the working directory for the run task. Here is an example:
    tasks.run.get().workingDir = rootProject.projectDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your build.gradle file to modify the working directory of a gradle task.

```
File runningDir = new File('build/run/')
runningDir.mkdirs()
tasks.run.workingDir = runningDir
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594196/gradle-application-plugin-modify-workingdir-property) thread for reference.