# Making Gradle access files outside its project

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build

I have a Gradle project which at some point in its code needs to act on a folder one level above the Gradle project's. It needs to write some data in it and create a file if it isn't there. However, the acting is the code's responsibility, all Gradle does is have a task which to run the code.

The problem is that when I run the gradle task, the jvm throws an `java.nio.File NoSuchFileException`.

Running the same program from Intellij's Run executes perfectly as intended, so it is not the code.

The one big difference I see is that the Intellij Run has a `Working directory` set at a level above my Kotlin project's, whereas Gradle is  pointing to the project as root, as it should be.

I am new to Gradle and I find the documentation hard to read, and it confused me quite a lot. I assume that I need to tell somehow Gradle that the code may need to access folders on the filesystem outside the project. However, I'm not sure if that needs to be in the `settings.gradle.kt` or on the task level and by using with which function.

Could you please point me the right way?

Answer (score 1):

To create a collection of files in a relative path, This snippet may work for you:

```
tasks.register('list') {
    doLast {
        File srcDir
        
        // Create a file collection using a closure
        collection = layout.files { srcDir.listFiles() }

        srcDir= file("../$rootDir")
        println "Contents of $srcDir.name"
        collection.collect { relativePath(it) }.sort().each { println it }
    }
}
```

reference website:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_collections

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I tad later realised that the issue specifically boils down to being able to change the working directory of the custom gradle task.
This was the topic that helped me although I came up with a 1-iner.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798844/customize-working-directory-run-gradle-run-task-project-structure-for-web-appl

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my previous comment the problem actually boiled down to having the ability to change the working directory of the custom Gradle task.

Inside a task I ended up doing the following:

```
run.configure {
   workingDir = File("./..")
}
```

This would make the scope of the working directory of the given task to be the one of its parent directory which solves the issue.