# Is there really no way to set the working directory for "gradle run"?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I do "gradle run", I'd like for the java command to be executed in my $projectDir/dist folder instad of project dir. This is where my application is getting built, it wouldn't make sense for it to run from the projectDir directly. From my research I keep seeing that this is somehow impossible? Is that really true? I've tried the following:

```
application() {
    mainClass.set("com.myapp.MainClass")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Duser.dir=$buildDir\\dist")
}
```

But that did not change the working directory. I can create another task:

```
tasks.register<JavaExec>("runApp") {
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    mainClass.set("com.myapp.MainClass")
    workingDir = file("$buildDir\\dist")
}
```

In which I can set the working directory, but it seems silly not to use the standard tasks that come with gradle. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Any existing task can be modified](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks), so long as you know its name. Knowing the type is also important (when using Groovy it is not critical, but can be very useful). So lets find out about the `run` task.

The Gradle Application plugin automatically creates [a task called `run`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks). `run` has the type [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html), which has a property, [`workingDir`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:workingDir), that defaults to the project directory.

Given this, we can now modify the existing `run` task in Groovy:

```groovy
// build.gradle
plugins {
  application
}

tasks.named('run') {
  workingDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
}
```

Or in Kotlin

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  application
}

tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
  workingDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
}
```

Note that the [Kotlin type-safe accessor](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors) for the `run` task clashes with the [`run {}` scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#run), and so `.configure {}` is required:

```kotlin
tasks.run {
  // doesn't configure the `run` task, because `run {}` is a scope function
}

// using .configure {} is required to configure the 'run' task:
tasks.run.configure {
  workingDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
}
```

#### See also

I also found these answers, but they are older and contain some outdated syntax, so I thought it was worth revisiting this question.

- [Gradle application plugin: Modify workingDir property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594196/gradle-application-plugin-modify-workingdir-property)
- [Customize working directory run gradle run task / project structure for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798844/customize-working-directory-run-gradle-run-task-project-structure-for-web-appl)

Comment: Thank you both very much for your answers!! That totally works and is quite simple.

Comment: Adding application give error: Cannot add task 'run' as a task with that name already exists
Not putting in application, error at named call: Task with name 'run' not found in root project

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reconfigure the `run` task to set the working directory. Assuming Kotlin build script language:

```kotlin
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    workingDir(file("$buildDir/dist"))
}
```